# Does a Java ranking class exist, increase/decrease, first/last rank

Tags: java

I'm in the process of creating a ranking class but was wondering if there is already any existing implementations.

Functionality needed (these will move the other ranks up/down appropriately) :

- increase/decrease rank
- move to first/last rank
- move to rank (x)
- check for any gaps in the rank, is so move the ranks around to get rid of the gaps. i.e. 1,2,4,5 will be updated to 1,2,3,4
- check duplicate ranks. If there are duplicate ranks, set one of them down a rank (probably the oldest object) and move the other objects down the ranks.
- Object getObjectAtRank(x)
- Int getObjectRank(object)

Are there any exisiting classes that I can extend or am I better off doing it from scratch?

Possibly with a Map using  but there would be problems with duplicate ranks etc.

Thanks!

**Edit** some additional info

The objects I am ranking are Jira Issues, these will have a rank field which I will read in so if an issue is deleted there could be a gap in the ranking.

Comment: Should "get element at rank 3" be a supported operation?

Comment: yep, a getElementAtRank(x) method should be available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't have any other constraints, I think `ArrayList` is sufficient for your needs:

- increase/decrease rank: Swap neighboring elements.
- move to first/last rank: Prepend/append using `add()`.
- move to rank (x): Insert using `add()`.
- check for any gaps in the rank: No need.
- check duplicate ranks: No need.

You cannot get the rank of an object in `O(1)` time though.

Answer (score 2):

How about a simple ArrayList? You could use the index as rank. The best part is you don't need to check for gaps or duplicate ranks.

```
void increaseRank(Object o) {
  int currentRank = list.indexOf(o);
  list.remove(o);
  list.add(o,currentRank - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any full implementation of what you want, but [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/)'s [`Range`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Range.html) class gets close, especially when used together with a [`DiscreteDomain`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/DiscreteDomain.html)

(unfortunately it's in version 10, which hasn't been released yet)

---

On re-reading the Question: you want to re-rank positions. Range does not seem to support that.

I think you should probably build your functionality around a simple `Arraylist`:

> increase/decrease rank
>   move to first/last rank
>   move to rank (x)

All of these can be achieved with [`Collections.swap(List, offset1, offset2)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#swap%28java.util.List,%20int,%20int%29)

> check for any gaps in the rank, is so move the ranks around to get rid of the gaps. i.e. 1,2,4,5 will be updated to 1,2,3,4

Irrelevant. Ranks are defined by List offset.

> check duplicate ranks. If there are duplicate ranks, set one of them down a rank (probably the oldest object) and move the other objects down the ranks.

ditto. There are no dupes, one element comes first